# How to programmatically set object properties in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

How can I use a dictionary of text names and values to set properties on an object?  For example...

I need to populate this object:

```
item = {};
```

Using this collection of values (note everything is a string):

```
values = [
    { id: 1, name: "a", value: "true" },
    { id: 2, name: "b", value: "false" },
    { id: 3, name: "c", value: "100" },
    { id: 4, name: "d", value: "me@nowhere.com" }
];
```

So that the original object looks like this:

```
item = {
    a: true,
    b: false,
    c: 100,
    d: 'me@nowhere.com'
}
```

Sorry for being so vague, but I'm not sure where to even start.

Answer (score 4):

You need to iterate over `values`, using the value of the `name` property of each item in that array as a key, and the value of the `value` property as the value:

```
var item = {}

values.forEach(function(i) {
  item[i.name] = i.value
})
```

Comment: Interesting.  But would this not make all of the values strings?

Comment: Yes. All of the values *are* strings. If you want to turn them into other types, you'll need to do some inspection of the value.

Comment: That's kinda critical.  Note the example.  Properties 'a' and 'b' are booleans.  Property 'c' is a number.  Property 'd' is a string.

Answer (score 2):

You can use reduce (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to reduce the array (in)to a single object

```
values.reduce(function(a, b){ 
    a[b.name] = b.value; 
    return a ;
}, item)
```

---

**Stack Snippet**

```js
var values = [
    { id: 1, name: "a", value: "true" },
    { id: 2, name: "b", value: "false" },
    { id: 3, name: "c", value: "100" },
    { id: 4, name: "d", value: "me@nowhere.com" }
];
var item = {};

so.log(values.reduce(function(a, b){ a[b.name] = b.value; return a }, item));
```

```css
body {
   font-family: verdana;
   font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="a"></div>
<script>
  var so = {
    log: function(e) {
       document.getElementById("a").innerText = JSON.stringify(e, null, '     ');
    }
  }
</script>
```

---

And if you also want to cast the string to the appropriate type, here is a rudimentary way of doing it

```
values
    // convert the properties - note that this CHANGES the values array
    // if you don't want to do that precede this by a .slice() - creates a copy of values
    .map(function (e) {
        // check if the string is true of false
        if (e.value === "true" || e.value === "false")
            e.value = (e.value === "true");
        // check if number
        else if (!isNaN(e.value))
            e.value = Number(e.value);
        return e;
    })
    .reduce(function (a, b) {
        a[b.name] = b.value;
        return a;
    }, item)
```

---

**Stack Snippet**

```js
var values = [
    { id: 1, name: "a", value: "true" },
    { id: 2, name: "b", value: "false" },
    { id: 3, name: "c", value: "100" },
    { id: 4, name: "d", value: "me@nowhere.com" }
];
var item = {};

so.log(values
    .map(function (e) {
        if (e.value === "true" || e.value === "false")
            e.value = (e.value === "true");
        else if (!isNaN(e.value))
            e.value = Number(e.value);
        return e;
    })
    .reduce(function (a, b) {
        a[b.name] = b.value;
        return a;
    }, item));
```

```css
body {
   font-family: verdana;
   font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="a"></div>
<script>
  var so = {
    log: function(e) {
       document.getElementById("a").innerText = JSON.stringify(e, null, '     ');
    }
  }
</script>
```

---

Comment: ''false'' remains string, it seems? String always returns true, right?

Comment: oh yes. sorry. just noticed that!

Comment: @nevermind - thanks! I always keep forgetting that Boolean("false") !== false

Comment: I think I accidentally clicked refresh or something on the other window midway through my edit. It should work now!

Comment: @nevermind - thanks for the link. that's a fun way to do it :-)

Comment: Np, i am the one who actually learning -> 'perpetual beginner'... :)

Answer (score 0):

In ES6:

```
Object.assign({}, ...values.map(value => ({[value.name]: value.value})))
```

This creates an array of little objects each with one key-value pair, using ES6's computed property names, then uses the spread operator (`...`) to pass them to `Object.assign` as parameters to be merged.

To transform the values, such as converting `"true"` to `true`, change `value.value` to `transform(value.value)` and write the `transform` function:

```
function transform(value) {
  return value === "true"  ? true   :
         value === "false" ? false  :
         !isNaN(value)     ? +value :
         value;
}
```